# ¿Me podríais explicar por favor por qué en esta frase se emplea el subjuntivo?

Tags: subjuntivo

> Entonces se iba feliz a su casa para no seguir desafiando al azar, pero después se sentía enloquecer de ansiedad **porque volvieran a ser todo el día las cinco de la tarde de todos los días**.

Normalmente en las oraciones causales el modo verbal va en indicativo... Entonces ¿por qué tenemos el subjuntivo aquí? ¿Hay algo hipotético en esta frase?

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

No se trata de una oración causal, sino de un complemento de *ansiedad*, que expresa el objeto de la misma. La oración subordinada va en subjuntivo porque expresa un deseo.

La RAE indica [en el DPD](http://www.rae.es/consultas/porque-porque-por-que-por-que) que en este caso lo correcto sería escribir *por que* en lugar de *porque*:

> - La preposición *por* + la conjunción subordinante *que*. Esta secuencia
>   aparece en el caso de verbos, sustantivos o adjetivos que rigen un
>   complemento introducido por la preposición *por* y llevan además una
>   oración subordinada introducida por la conjunción *que*:
>
> Al final optaron por que no se presentase.
>
> Están **ansiosos por que empecemos** a trabajar en el proyecto.
>
> Nos confesó su preocupación por que los niños pudieran enfermar.

Sin embargo, es bastante común encontrarse con *porque* en lugar de *por que* en estos casos, probablemente porque oralmente son indistinguibles.

Notar que *ansioso* tiene dos acepciones:

> **[ansioso, sa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2lENUCe)**
>
> Del lat. *anxiōsus*.
>
> 1. adj. Acompañado de ansias o congojas grandes.
> 2. adj. **Que tiene ansia o deseo vehemente de algo.**

La segunda requiere un complemento, la primera puede llevar una oración causal:

> Estoy ansioso porque son las cinco de la tarde. (y es un momento del día que no me gusta)
>
> Estoy ansioso por que sean las cinco de la tarde. (y sé que algo bueno va a pasar)

La principal pista para distinguir entre una y otra situación no es el espacio entre *por* y *que*, que no existe oralmente, sino el modo del verbo.

En el caso del fragmento de García Marquez está expresando el deseo permanente del personaje de que vuelvan a ser las cinco de la tarde, el momento en que se encuentra con su amante.

Answer (score 1):

No es el subjuntivo.

Es un buen ejemplo del **pluscuamperfecto simple del indicativo** que tiene muy poco uso en el español moderno. Solo suele disfrutar de uso en textos muy literarios, algunos textos periodísticos, y en el habla de los hablantes que también hablan el gallego o el asturiano que han mantenido este modo para las formas *-ra-*.

Puédese reescribir la frase sustituyendo la forma con *-ra-* por el imperfecto del indicativo de *haber* con el participio pasado del verbo original así formando el pluscuamperfecto compuesto del indicativo sin cambiar su significado:

> Entonces se iba feliz a su casa para no seguir desafiando al azar, pero después se sentía enloquecer de ansiedad *porque **habían vuelto** a ser todo el día las cinco de la tarde de todos los días.*

He aquí un trozo de la *Nueva Gramática* de la RAE sobre el tema:

> **§24.2i.** El uso de **cantara** como forma del subjuntivo comenzó a extenderse en el siglo XV, especialmente a partir de las oraciones condicionales y de otros contextos modales, y se hallaba afianzado en el Siglo de Oro.  El antiguo empleo de **cantara** por **había cantado**, que había experimentado un declive progresivo en los siglos XVI y XVII, fue retomado por algunos escritores en los siglos XVIII y XIX por imitación de los usos antiguos.  Estos usos de **cantara** eran muy comunes en la lengua literaria de esos siglos y permanecen hoy vivos en las hablas dialectales del noroeste de la Península Ibérica.  Así *adquieran* significa ‘habían adquirido’ (o bien ‘hubieran adquirido’) en el texto siguiente: *Había contado con el éxito de operaciones bien preparadas y con las posiciones que adquirieran sus hijos* (Goldós, *León Roch*).  La extensión tuvo éxito, y hoy es frecuente en la lengua literaria —y más aún en la periodística y la ensayística— de casi todos los países hispanohablantes.  Se suele entender entender que **cantara** pertenecer aquí propiamente al paradigma del indicativo, de acuerdo con la distinción introducida en el § 24.1d.

Puédese leer algunos ejemplos en dicha sección y sobre algunas de las restricciones en su empleo (exceptuando en los dialectos del noroeste de España en los que substituye por el pluscuamperfecto totalmente) en § 24.2j

Comment: ¿Podría el (o ella) que votó en negativo explicar por qué no está de acuerdo con mi respuesta?

Comment: ahí agregué mi respuesta.

Comment: El significado cambia, lq respuesta de @rsanchez es la correcta