# ¿"por que" o "porque"?

Tags: sintaxis, conjunciones

> Entonces se iba feliz a su casa para no seguir desafiando al azar,
>   pero después se sentía enloquecer de ansiedad **porque** volvieran a ser
>   todo el día las cinco de la tarde de todos los días.

[*El amor en los tiempos del cólera*, Editorial Debols!llo]

No entiendo si es un error tipográfico o si es de verdad correcto. ¿Debemos escribirlo separado → *asiedad por algo* (con valor final)? ¿O tiene valor causal?

Comment: Ver https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15481/me-podr%c3%adais-explicar-por-favor-por-qu%c3%a9-en-esta-frase-se-emplea-el-subjuntivo

Answer (score 4):

Parece ser un error (del autor, nunca corregido, o de la edición), ya que efectivamente el uso normal es *ansiedad por [objeto]*, donde el [objeto] en este caso sería la proposición subordinada *que volvieran a ser...*. El valor es de finalidad; dado el uso del subjuntivo en la subordinada, que aquí denota deseo, no cabe interpretar que sea causal.

El servicio de consultas de la RAE lo explica en su artículo sobre la [diferencia entre *porqué*, *porque*, *por qué* y *por que*](http://www.rae.es/consultas/porque-porque-por-que-por-que); es el último de los casos considerados, donde se encuentra "la preposición *por* + la conjunción subordinante *que*". Hay justamente un ejemplo con *ansiedad por...*:

> *Están ansiosos **por que** empecemos a trabajar en el proyecto.*